# Selection sort in Python yields no output

Tags: python, algorithm, pycharm, selection-sort

I'm trying to run selection sort in python, this is the code that I'm using

```
def main(list):
    input_array = [12, 9, 13, 7, 3, 19, 6, 5]
    output_array = selection_sort(input_array)
    print(output_array)


def selection_sort(param):

    for i in range(0, (len(param) - 1)):
        min = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(param)):
            if param[min] < param[j]:
                min = j

            if min != i:
                temp = param[i]
                param[i] = param[min]
                param[min] = temp
    return param
```

The output that I get is

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm using PyCharm as the idea, if that's of any consequence.

Comment: how can `min, i, j, temp = 0` work? You are also shadowing the builtin `list`  and the builtin `min`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- input_array should be a list, you are making it a set

  ```
  input_array = [12, 9, 13, 7, 3, 19, 6, 5]
  ```
- don't use the variable name list, it is the name for the built-in list
- don't use min as a variable name, it is the name for the built-in function min
- you don't need an argument for your main method here
- you are not calling your main method, call it after the definition of `selection_sort`
- change the line

  ```
  minimum, i, j, temp = 0
  ```

  to

  ```
  minimum, i, j, temp = 0, 0, 0, 0
  ```

Comment: This code seems to work but I've a few questions, one the output array is largest first, second why have you reversed the sequence of the functions and why're you calling main() in the end. I'm a bit new to python.

Comment: Hey Clockwork. You could also put the definition of `main` before the definition of `selection_sort`, as long as you still issue the call to `main` at the end of the script. I am explicitly calling `main` at the end because `main` is just a function, and if you want it to run, you need to call it. This behavior is different to Java, where the main method is called automatically. The elements of the result are in descending order because you coded it that way :) Have another look at your logic, or reverse the list with `list(reversed(output_array))`.

Answer (score 0):

This will sort in ascending order:

```
def selection_sort(my_list):
    for j in range(len(my_list)):
        for i in range(j, len(my_list)):
            if my_list[i] < my_list[j]:
                my_list[j], my_list[i] = my_list[i], my_list[j]
    return my_list



def main():
    input_array = [12, 9, 13, 7, 3, 19, 6, 5]
    output_array = selection_sort(input_array)
    print(output_array)
[3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 19]
```